# Unable to make navigation drawer activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, navigation

I have created a news app in which I want to use navigation drawer,but when I add a navigation drawer activity it is giving some errors.Even if I make a new project with navgiation drawer properties,its still giving errors.
I have created a news app in which I want to use navigation drawer,but when I add a navigation drawer activity it is giving some errors.Even if I make a new project with navgiation drawer properties,its still giving errors.

```
    > Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
       Warning: Failed to parse host Vitika
       Warning: Failed to parse host Vitika
       Failed to parse host Vitika


       Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with    Gradle 7.0.
       Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings. 
       See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings


       Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk16:1.3.72.
       Show Details
       Affected Modules: app

       Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not             resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk16:1.3.72.
        Show Details
        Affected Modules: app

        Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk16:1.3.72.
       Show Details
       Affected Modules: app
```

Build.gradle(Project:News)

```
        // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all          sub-projects/modules.
     buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

         allprojects {
          repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        }
    }

      task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
       }
```

Build.gradle(Module:app)

```
     plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

     android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vitika.news"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        //noinspection DataBindingWithoutKapt
        dataBinding true
    }
    repositories{
        maven{ url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'}
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk16:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
    def fragment_version = "1.3.3"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    def nav_version = "2.3.5"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Feature module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"

    // Jetpack Compose Integration
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha10"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'


}
```

gradle.properties

```
## For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
#
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

    #
    # When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
    # This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
    # http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
    # org.gradle.parallel=true
    #Wed May 19 16:22:21 IST 2021
    systemProp.https.proxyHost=Vitika
    systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Available jdk is jdk8 or jdk7 not jdk16.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
```